# How to tell if parameters are correlated by looking at the covariance matrix?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance, correlation

I have the following density function which is a mixture of bivariate Gaussian distributions -

\begin{equation*}
 f(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{N}_2(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I}_2)+\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{N}_2\biggl\{\left(\begin{array}{c}-6 \\-6\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0.9 \\0.9 & 1\end{array}\right)\biggr\}+\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{N}_2\biggl\{\left(\begin{array}{c}4 \\4\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & -0.9 \\-0.9 & 1\end{array}\right)\biggr\}
\end{equation*}

My question is - how do I assess whether or not the parameters are correlated by examining the covariance matrices?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I could not understand the line(My question ...), can you explain elaborately?

Comment: Basically, I mean I want to be able to tell whether or not the components of $\mathbf{x} = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ are correlated by looking at the covariance matrices in the pdf.

Comment: you can easily check that $Cov(X_1,X_2)=0$ using definition. But "by looking at the covariance matrices in the pdf" is not a good idea always.